move copies instead of moves
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (%file_list%) DO (move "%src_folder%\%%i" "%dst_folder%")

This resulted in copy instead of move.
I need to remove the files from the source folder.

/Y                      Suppresses prompting to confirm you want to
overwrite an existing destination file.

FOR %%A IN ("%SourceDir%\*.*") DO XCOPY /F /Y "%%~A" "%DestDir%\" && DEL /Q /F "%%~A"

Thank you very much.
Still wondering why MOVE copied, though.

This was on the same drive.
I need to separate out 8000+ files from a folder of about 32000.
I really don't want to do it by hand.

I adapted your syntax for delete to my script and it moved successfully but reports "couldn't find %%~A.
What does the %%~A do?

The %%~A should be full explicit path of the file in the loop array for the iterated value—it cancels out the double quotes so I always enclose in double quotes. I got that from another one of my SU answers from long ago. I don't do much in batch any longer and automate with PowerShell now. I vaguely recall with SFTP processes I maintained and WinSCP file transfer automation, the copy, then delete worked better with batch. I always added conditional IF EXIST before delete, etc. though to adjust for validation needs. That was from a simple SU answer script I posted once for an example.

Test with echo %%~A to see and find any anomalies. Batch solutions got caveats, so you will know or see one if that's what is going on. Compare counts, etc. too. What batch counts, what files in Explorer counts, etc. Play with PowerShell for automation when you can.
